# Get entry_points console_scripts for a complex structure

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to generate my executable scripts upon python setuptools.
My project structure is:

```
.project
├── ./lib
│   ├── ./source/tasker.py
│   ├── ./source/__init__.py
│   ├── ./__init__.py
│   ├── ./settings.py
│
├── ./README.md
├── ./setup.py
```

My entry point:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'command=lib.source.tasker:main',
    ]
},
```

But it gives an Import Error:

```
ImportError: No module named source.tasker
load_entry_point('project==0.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'command')()
```

Comment: It's tasker.py , I had a typo edited the question

Answer (score 0):

If your module is named "tracker.py", shouldn't your entry point be:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'command=lib.source.tracker:main',
    ]
},
```

Comment: apologies there was a typo.

Comment: If you run the python shell from the .project directory (same level as the setup.py, are you able to successfully run: "from lib.source.tasker import main" ?

Comment: In an interpreter yes, u can check my repo https://github.com/arindampradhan/learnpython

Answer (score 0):

Fine I figured out what was the issue:

I missed adding the source dir **lib.source** to packages in setup.py

```
packages=['lib','lib.source'],
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'learnpython = lib.source.tasker:main',
    ]
},
```